# Test Class to verify fields updated the same as the expected output

Tags: apex, unit-test, list

I'm creating my first test class got stuck with this one could you help me verify and correct the line of code for me.

```
 //Create a new record for Address Object with Local record type   
        List<Address__c> addressRecord = new List<Address__c>();
        //Map<id, id> mapAdd = new Map<id, id>();
        addressRecord = TestDataFactory.createAddress(2);


        addressRecord[0].recordTypeID = ConstantsSLB.getKeyId('Address_Local');
        addressRecord[0].Name = 'Address Test';
        addressRecord[0].Postal_Code__c = postal.Id; 
        addressRecord[0].Unit_Number__c = '12';
        addressRecord[0].Level_Number__c = '13';

        addressRecord[1].recordTypeID = ConstantsSLB.getKeyId('Address_Local');
        addressRecord[1].Name = 'Address Test';
        addressRecord[1].Postal_Code__c = ' '; 
        addressRecord[1].Unit_Number__c = '13';
        addressRecord[1].Level_Number__c = '10';

        insert addressRecord;

        //This will verify if the fields updated are same as the expected output.
        addressRecord = [SELECT Building_Name__c, Block_House_Number__c, Street_Name__c, Address_Type__c FROM Address__C WHERE Id = :addressRecord.Id];

        System.assertEquals(postal.Building_Name__c, addressRecord[0].Building_Name__c);
        System.assertEquals(postal.House_Block_Number__c, addressRecord[0].Block_House_Number__c);
        System.assertEquals(postal.Street_Name__c, addressRecord[0].Street_Name__c);
        System.assertEquals(postal.Address_Type__c, addressRecord[0].Address_Type__c);

        addressRecord[0].Postal_Code__c = postal.Id;
        addressRecord[1].Postal_Code__c = ' ';

        update addressRecord;
```

Comment: so what isn't working?

Comment: got a problem with line addressRecord = [SELECT Building_Name__c,... it says Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<Address__c>

Comment: You are saying where Id = :addressRecord.Id, which is a list, you would have to reference a specific record in that list, i.e addressRecord[0].Id. Not sure exactly what you want to accomplish but that is the source of the error.

Comment: from the created address record will need to verify the fields updated in that line of code...

        addressRecord = [SELECT Building_Name__c, Block_House_Number__c, Street_Name__c, Address_Type__c FROM Address__C WHERE Id = :addressRecord.Id];

        //System.assertEquals...

        addressRecord[0].Postal_Code__c = postal.Id;
        addressRecord[1].Postal_Code__c = ' ';

        update addressRecord;

update the first addressrecord with postal id while the other one is blank.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
addressRecord = [SELECT Building_Name__c, Block_House_Number__c, Street_Name__c, Address_Type__c 
                  FROM Address__C WHERE Id = :addressRecord.Id];
```

Since addressRecord is a List, the SOQL needs to be

```
addressRecord = [SELECT Building_Name__c, Block_House_Number__c, Street_Name__c, Address_Type__c 
                  FROM Address__C WHERE Id IN :addressRecord];
```

this will return a list of Address__c using the IDs of the inserted Address__c.

As a side note, you could make your life much easier by using better variable names - specifically, in this declaration

You have:

```
List<Address__c> addressRecord = new List<Address__c>();
```

you should use something like this:

```
List<Address__c> addressRecordList = new List<Address__c>();
```

as the word `addressRecord` implies singular

Comment: Had to up-vote for mentioning the use of better variable names. I've cleaned up numerous examples where a List of Accounts is a or some terse derivative. Drives me nuts.

Comment: hehe -- just yesterday I gave a lecture to colleagues on best practices - confusingly-named variables and methods was one of the topics.